# rewriterule on regular expression, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, expression

This isn't working,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^res/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /server/entry.php?PAGENAME=$1 [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 403 /notfound
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound
```

I think the last code is not working, I have tried to change ^.* -> (.*) but the result was the same.

I could be wrong, but this last line is the one with wrong statement, but I dont know what to do with it anymore. Tried all I could.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /server/entry.php?PAGENAME=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Been struggling on this for 2 days now... I have done research online and tried other codes but didn't work either.

Comment: Yes the last rule needs to be a capture group. Please explain what you're trying to do. You only put the code but not what you expect to happen. Also do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment! I finally figured it out, RewriteRule ^.*$ server/entry.php?PAGENAME=$0 [QSA,L] -< this went ok

Comment: Seems like i shouldnt put / before the server it could be a setting of the server. Took me couple days to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

This didnt work,

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /server/entry.php?PAGENAME=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This worked,

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ server/entry.php?PAGENAME=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Probably the setting of the server, but I shouldnt use the absolute path.

Comment: Actually you can use that, but the correct rule is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server/entry.php?PAGENAME=$1 [QSA,L]` I just don't want others who see this answer to think thats the right way to do it. Because  `$0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.` That is not generally what people need.

Comment: Hi, Panama thank you very much for comment. I would love to know the correct way, will test out.